# Apply a theme to an activity in Android?

Tags: android, themes, manifest

I know how to apply a theme to a whole application, but where would I go to apply a theme to just a single activity?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can apply a theme to any activity by including `android:theme` inside `<activity>` inside manifest file.

For example:

1. `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`
2. `<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">`

And if you want to set theme programatically then use `setTheme()` before calling `setContentView()` and `super.onCreate()` method inside `onCreate()` method.

Comment: What about disable theme? on a single activity

Comment: @Yousha Aleayoub: did you try just setting another theme?

Comment: No, but i just want to disable/remove the theme and make it basic... :)

Comment: and in activity xml use `tools:context= ".YourAtivityName"` in the root

Answer (score 37):

To set it programmatically in Activity.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setTheme(R.style.MyTheme); // (for Custom theme)
  setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo); // (for Android Built In Theme)

  this.setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
```

To set in Application scope in Manifest.xml (all activities):

```
 <application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

To set in Activity scope in Manifest.xml (single activity):

```
  <activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

To build a custom theme, you will have to declare theme in 
themes.xml file, and set styles in styles.xml file.

Comment: What about disable theme? on a single activity

Comment: Why have you added two `android:theme` attributes?

Comment: @Vineet Kaushik, `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` is the syntax for adding an Android built-in theme.  `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` is the syntax for adding a custom theme described in your `styles.xml` file.  In your actual `AndroidManifest.xml` file you would only use one or the other for each section, not both.

Comment: @Yousha Aleayoub, to disable the theme, create a blank theme in `styles.xml` and then use the syntax `android:theme=@style/MyBlankTheme`.

Comment: It seems putting more than one custom theme in the manifest don't work. If you add a theme at application level and a second at activity level, only the application one is used. I tried to add one theme for each activity with different "look" but without good result.

Answer (score 8):

Before you call `setContentView()`, call `setTheme(android.R.style...)` and just replace the ... with the theme that you want(Theme, Theme_NoTitleBar, etc.).

Or if your theme is a custom theme, then replace the entire thing, so you get `setTheme(yourThemesResouceId)`