# Android Lollipop recents/multitasking header styling, text always black

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

It seems switching between Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and Theme.AppCompat.Light has no effect on the text color and "close" button inside the recents menu. `colorPrimary` changes the header color, but the text and button are always black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For as far as I can tell you **cannot** change the color of the label text and close button because it is automatically set by the system. The only things that you can control are the icon, bar color, and label text via:

```
Activity.setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(label, icon, color));
```

You can test and see how the system automatically chooses the label and close button colors by supplying a dark or light color to the above function (i.e. set it to black, the text will be white and vice versa).

Docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Recents
Javadocs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)

-- EDIT --
Here's more details on how the platform determines the text color for the tasks.

The SystemUI app shows the recent task UI. It has a Task model [Task.java:156](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/model/Task.java#L156) which detects if the contrast between your colorPrimary (specified in the task description) and white is above 3 it will use the light color. See [Utilities.java:119](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/misc/Utilities.java#L119) on how the contrast computation is done.

The text colors used for light and dark can be found here in SystemUI's [colors.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/packages/SystemUI/res/values/colors.xml#L61).

Comment: How can you make sure the text color is white?

Answer (score 9):

[r0adkll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634804/2320322) is correct in that using `Activity.setTaskDescription()` gives you control over the background color, the icon (which **should** be square or else it is stretched) and the label. If you don't call `Activity.setTaskDescription()` at all though, and let the system style the Recents header itself, it will do the following:

- The icon will be the activity's icon as set by `android:icon` in the manifest (**not** `android:logo`)
- The label will be the activity's label as set by `android:label` in the manifest
- The background color will be the [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125267/2320322)'s `android:colorPrimary`

The label (and close button) color will be light or dark depending on how dark or light the background is. There is no way to change the typeface of the label.