# How to change Android Lollipop Overview/Recents/Multitasking textColor

Tags: xml, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles

How do you change the text color of your apps recents "card" in lollipop?

The following do **not** work:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#171717</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Nobody has any idea how to do this?..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Lollipop recents/multitasking header styling, text always black](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532651/android-lollipop-recents-multitasking-header-styling-text-always-black)

Comment: @Micharl Did you figure this out?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I did. (Here is a link to the answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39726859/2415921). I wish we had more control over the color combos, but the answer I posted will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error I found the answer.

Android "auto generates" the white (or black) text based on primary color in your `styles.xml`. This is pretty lame of Google to handle it this way because using certain color backgrounds may still look good with white text.

---

**resources/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Something">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item> <!-- Must be dark enough to make android generate white text -->
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you and thank your for posting. See this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899820/android-5-0-how-to-change-recent-apps-title-color/27703150#comment66730493_27703150