# Ionic2 / Cordova: How to update Android theme-color?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to replicate the following effect via Cordova?

On our web platform we are able to change theme color using the following meta tag:

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">`

as explained in the following article

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

[image: Theme Color]

Comment: Maybe my plugin could help you: [Changing color of header in multitask view?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38431691/4359029)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing color of header in multitask view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838528/changing-color-of-header-in-multitask-view)