# How to configure Status Bar color when application is loading with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I created an application with Cordova. I want to improve the UI/UX so it looks like a native application, as much as possible.

When the application loads for the 1st time, the first milliseconds (less than 1 second actually) the Status Bar (and Background) has not the color I configured with the [Cordova Plugin for Status Bar](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/), as you can see there.

[image]

This blue is something linked to my Android Version/Installation, all menus and settings have the same mandatory color. The Android Version I have currently is 7.0

After the first milliseconds, the Status Bar and the Background become the ones I actually configured.

[image]

Also, when I open the menu of recent applications, we find this same color. I'd like to set that color. Is this possible?

[image]