# Change Theme Colors Programatically to any Color in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

**What I Want**

I have has got a pre-defined color as the primary and accent color. But not all my users like the color I like. So, I want to create a color chooser with 10-15 predefined colors, which the user can choose to make as his/her primary and accent color.

I have read that the styles.xml file is immutable, so what is the way I can achieve this. I have seen many apps like Talon for Twitter Plus and many more doing this.

How can I do this? A working solution would be really appreciated.

EDIT - The user can select between Light theme and Dark theme. And there will be some preset colors which when selected will change the primary color and accent color of the theme, so that any widget in the app using these two colors get changed automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

Comment: @RobertRowntree This is just to pick colors. Can it change the primary and accent color in the styles.xml?

Comment: create your set of alternates in styles/themes xml files then in activity, before you set content view, change to desire theme... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android

Comment: @RobertRowntree This seems to be a much better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Which parts of your app do you want to change?

Easiest way would be to write your colors in a color.xml file and simply change the background colors of your parts.