# How to make every activity has a different color AppBar?

Tags: android

I have a main activity qual touching default colors AppBar color is brown, but I want a secondary activity that the bar is green and one yellow. So that each activity has a different color.

This is what I've tried:

It applies to all activities

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

I wanted applies only to one but not how it works

```
<style name="CapAlumnes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/botoAlumnes</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/botoAlumnes</item>
</style>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a theme to an activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android)

Comment: Set a different theme in Android Manifest for each activity

Answer (score 2):

Create different themes in styles with different primary and secondary colors. 
Set each one of these themes to your individual activities in the Android manifest file.

```
<activity name="xyz" theme="styles/    mythemeColorGreen />

<activity name="xyd" theme="styles/     mythemeColorBlue />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity onCreate:

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.botoAlumnes)));
```

If APK >= 16

```
mToolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.botoAlumnes)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use the `android:background` attribute in your XML layouts.

Comment: If all you need is to change the background, you are correct.  However, `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` do more than that, so if you need all the effects of changing these items, (like changing the color of the status bar) using themes is the correct answer.