# Theme Material Android: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library

Tags: android

I got error message like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

for temp.xml (layout) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="490dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

manifest:

```
 <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- theme customizations -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and gradle app:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bippo.co.id.bidapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
:
:
```

I have read [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity):

1. NO extends to `ActionBarActivity`, but the class extends to `FragmentActivity`
2. I want to use Theme Material Light

please share what should I do :)

@Michael Spitsin:
I have tried different theme foreach activity (on manifest):

```
<application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FormLogin" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity android:name=".FormRegister" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity android:name=".FormAccountView" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity android:name=".FormSearch" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity android:name=".FormItemView" android:theme="@style/CoordinatorTheme"/>

        <activity android:name=".Temp" android:theme="@style/CoordinatorTheme" />

    </application>
```

and sytles + styles-21:

```
<!-- your theme inherits from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- theme customizations -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- coordinator layout. -->
    <style name="CoordinatorTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

but I still got the msg error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'd assume that the CoordinatorLayout requires `Theme.AppCompat` (or descendant). So you most likely can't use it when you want to stick to `Theme.Material.Light`.

Comment: Where is your appcomact gradle dependancy

Comment: Sorry for late I respon..
@Dodge, yup you are right

Comment: Sorry for late I respon..
@AbhayBohra, it is compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' (only one)

Comment: Sorry for late I respon..
@MikeM, no duplicate with different values, in values and values-v21 there is only one "AppTheme", it is <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

Comment: No. Read the answer. The fact that that user has a slightly different setup doesn't matter. The answer is the same. Just use `Theme.AppCompat`; specifically `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, in your case . It "already extends `android:Theme.Material` on API 21+".

Comment: @Mike M, sorry for my missed, ok i will try your suggestion..

Comment: @Mike M, you were right :), thank you

Answer (score 3):

This happens because in constructor of `CoordinatorLayout` there is a line:

```
ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(context);
```

And also you can see then through the stacktrace of your Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
```

So you need to provide AppCompat theme if you want to use `CoordinatorLayout`.

**UPDATE**

If you still want to use material theme and coordinator layout, as compromise you can provide AppCompat theme only for Activity that uses `CoordinatorLayout` through `android:theme` attribute in `<activity>` tag in the manifest. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android) for more details.

Comment: Sorry for late I respond.. I have tried your suggestion on the above comment. I still got the error message..

Comment: @RudiWijaya Hi. Is stacktrace same as first one?

Comment: Sorry for late again.. @Michael Spitsin, yes it is them same of stacktrace :(

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your application tag in menifest

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

<application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        ...

        </application>
```

and in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

By @Mike M's suggestion:
I used

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

It's resolved