# Setting new ActionBar in a certain activity when it was disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android development, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I have disabled Action Bar in AndroidManifest.xml like this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` but I'm in need of Action Bar in a certain activity. How do I create and set new Action Bar only to that activity?

Edit: 
I forgot to mention that the activity I want to have an Action Bar is child of the activity with no Action Bar. I guess this causes the problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a theme to an activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Define the theme for that perticular activity in the menifest.

```
<activity
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is for this problem

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" android:label="activity_with_actionbar" />
```

And

```
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:label="activity_with_no_actionbar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the opposite, i.e., In `AndroidManifest` keep theme as  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

and in Activities that you **dont** want to see ActionBar, add below code in its `onCreate` method:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add theme specifically for each activity inside manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Action bar. And implement **ActionBar** class in the activity u needed to have an action bar. Its very easy way to do what you want. Follow [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) tutorial.