# Can I style all AppBarLayouts in my app from my app theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appbarlayout

I want to remove the shadows by default for all AppBarLayouts in my app. I know I can remove it by putting `app:elevation="0dp"` in the AppBarLayout tag of my layout xml, but I want to do it in my app theme so it's automatically done for all AppBarLayouts in my app. How can I style my AppBarLayouts from my app theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a theme of your own and apply it to entire application from Manifest file.
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125267/1264496

Comment: I know how to define a theme, but I can't find anything to style the AppBarLayout.